# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly despite adding .encode() to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to write some code that connects to an IRC channel and allows the user to chat through the channel. I have been getting an error in my script that connects to the server:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

The error is apparently in line 18, which is the code that sends the nickname to the server:

```
irc.send("USER " + nick.encode() + " " + nick.encode() + " " + nick.encode() + " : Test\n")
```

Source Code:

```
import sys
import socket

server = "chat.freenode.net"
channel = "#randomchannel123456789"
port = 7070

print("IRC Connecter")
print("-----------------------------")
nick = input("Input Nickname: ")

irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("connecting to " + server)

irc.connect((server, port))
print("connected")

irc.send("USER " + nick.encode() + " " + nick.encode() + " " + nick.encode() + " : Test\n")
print("sent user")

irc.send ("NICK " + nick + "\n")
print("sent nick")

while 1:
   text = irc.recv(2040)
   print(text)

   if text.find("PING") != -1:
      irc.send("PONG " + text.split() [1] + "\r\n")
```

I'm pretty new to socket programming, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Lose the `encode()` on your `nick` - encode the whole string once you concatenate it (i.e. `("USER " + nick + " " + nick + " " + nick + " : Test\n").encode()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in that line:

```
"USER " + nick.encode() + " " + nick.encode() + " " + nick.encode() + " : Test\n"
```

The `"USER "`, `" "` and `" : Test\n"` are `str` but `nick.encode` is a `bytes` object. And the exception is telling you, that you can't add `bytes` and `str`s:

```
>>> b'a' + 'a'
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

>>> 'a' + b'a'
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

You could convert the string literals to bytes, for example using the bytes literal (`b""`):

```
b"USER " + nick.encode() + b" " + nick.encode() + b" " + nick.encode() + b" : Test\n"
```

Comment: Ah! It's working now. Thanks, I never would have figured that out on my own! Haha